# Using Intel Smart Response Technology (IRST) with Linux only?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, intel-rst

I have an existing Fedora 20 installation and would like to use my newly bought 64GB SSD for acceleration purposes.

Since I have a mainboard that supports Intel SRT, and RST with that, I was wondering if I could use the RAID setup utility to create an SSD cache for the existing harddrive to accelerate my setup.
Would that work with linux at all? If so, are there any special requirements?

I can't use `bcache` since it requires superblocks on the devices which would erase my current data.

Answer (score 1):

Intel Smart Response Technology isn't supported on Linux.  If you have a small amount of RAM, consider putting your swap space on the SSD.  Otherwise I would suggest cloning your drive in a way that would allow you to use [bcache](http://www.forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1681469#post1681469).

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it but you could use it like this:

1. Install windows, activate smart response, delete windows, install linux.
2. Try activating it from UEFI, not sure how.